# Topic modelling with many synonyms - how to extract 'latent themes'

Tags: nlp, topic-model, lda

Here's my corpus

```
{
    0: "dogs are nice",       # canines are friendly
    1: "mutts are kind",      # canines are friendly
    2: "pooches are lovely",  # canines are friendly
    ...,
    3: "cats are mean",         # felines are unfriendly
    4: "moggies are nasty",     # felines are unfriendly
    5: "pussycats are unkind",  # felines are unfriendly
}
```

As a human, the general topics I get from these documents are that:

- canines are friendly (0, 1, 2)
- felines are not friendly (3, 4, 5)

But how can a machine find the same conclusion?

If I were to do a Latent Dirichlet Allocation approach, I feel like it would struggle to find topics because the synonyms are 'diluting' the underlying meaning. For example:

- "dogs", "pooches", and "mutts" could all fall under "canines"
- "nice", "kind", and "lovely" could all fall under "friendly personality trait"

Is there a way where I can use an already-trained set of latent vectors (e.g., [Google News-vectors-negative300.bin.gz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit)) to represent each document in these broader entities, and *then* find the topics? (i.e., instead of using the 'raw' words)

Does that even make sense?

---

EDIT: Come to think of it, I think my question essentially boils down to: **is it possible to replace/redefine a set of similar-meaning words with a single all-encompassing word?**

Comment: You could try to learn an embedding such that similar words are close together or just use a pretrained model.

Comment: I agree with what the user @bonfab said above. You can use a pre-trained model (say word2vec on a large corpus) such that the embeddings of such words are nearly similar and build topic modelling on top of that (essentially clustering).

Answer (score 0):

One option is start with pattern matching with established tools. For each statement, find the subject and sentiment.

Here are off-the-shelf tools (no training or machine learning):

- WordNet a large lexical database of English words.
- Synset is a way to find instances are the groupings of synonymous
  words that express the same concept.
- SentiWordNet assigns to each synset of WordNet.